# PostGIS query on having their centroid in the source layer feature

Tags: postgis

I am trying to port the ArcMap query by location ("Have their centroid in the source layer feature") to PostGIS. The aim is to select all feature that are completely within and touches the source layer. Currently, my ST_Intersect & ST_Within are not giving me the results I want.

```
SELECT     a.*, b.* 
FROM       town a
INNER JOIN local b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Comment: That query would return two geometries, which will not work in ArcGIS, even if the relationship was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all features in table a, having their centroids in table b:

```
select a.*
from yourschema.A a
join yourschema.B b
on st_intersects(st_centroid(a.geom), b.geom)
```

[image]